# Rails - set default association on delete of has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, associations

What i'm trying to do - I have  have many`Profile`s each of which has many `User`s. I have a default Profile. What i want to do is on Profile's delete to associate Users from a deleted Profile to a default one. do Something like:

```
class Profile
  has_many :users, dependent: :set_default
  def set_default
  #set default value on destroy
  end
end

class User
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

How can i do that?
PS. Example code was shortened to include only essential information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override your getter for profile association:

```
def profile
  user.profile_id ? Profile.find(id) : user.default_profile
end
```

`default_profile` is your method that will return default profile.

Also you can use `alias_method`:

```
alias_method :original_profile, :profile

def profile
  original_profile || user.default_profile
end
```